# Networkx- IndexError: list index out of range while using (greedy_modularity_communities

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, modularity

I am using Python 3.7.1 and networkx 2.2.
I used networkx to generate my directed graph and I want to calculate the communities of the graph with [networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max.greedy_modularity_communities](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max.greedy_modularity_communities.html#networkx.algorithms.community.modularity_max.greedy_modularity_communities)
in following steps:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.community import greedy_modularity_communities
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,10])
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,1),(2,10),(3,8),(9,8)])
c = list(greedy_modularity_communities(G))
sorted(c[0])
```

I recive an error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you provide the full error message, and a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure, I added the code example in the question, and the full error message is as I wrote before the IndexError.

Comment: The full error message will contain more information than just the index error (for example it will say what line in which package produced the error).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your problem is that your graph is directed.  The documentation of `greedy_modularity_communities` suggests that it expects the input to be a `Graph`, but yours is a `DiGraph`.

If I do

```
H = nx.Graph(G)
c = list(greedy_modularity_communities(H))
```

I do not get an error.  I'm not sure whether the communities it finds in `H` will be what you're interested in.